# Mention userid with discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
if message.content == '-CheckNico':
        await message.channel.send(Nico)
```

I need to mention a user of discord  on (message content), for example, instead of `-CheckNico` as a command, I have to  mention the user id on my server.  example --> - `@2647388376563834` (user id)

I don't have any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can mention a user using `<@id>` or `<@!id>` if you want to include their nickname. You can see more information at the [discord api docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting).